# Center the values in a dropdown

Tags: html

i have the following piece of code for a dropdown in html, and I am attempting to center the vaues that the dropdown contains. I imagine 'center' would have to be used or align="center" however wherever i put them it wont center. could anyone point out where the tag would go?

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" align="center" action="section_search_results.php">
      <p>Select The <b>Section</b> You Wish To Search Below...      </p>
      <p><center>
        <label for="section"></label>
        <label for="section2"></label>
        <select name="section" id="section2">
<option value="Functional">Functional</option>
<option value="Technical">Technical</option>
<option value="Commercial">Commercial</option>
<option value="Implementation">Implementation</option>
<option value="Innovation">Innovation</option></center>
        </select>
```

Thanks

Comment: Finding things in centred columns of text is considerably harder than doing so in columns that are left aligned. Please don't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I imagine 'center' would have to be used or align="center"

No. CSS 2 was published in 1998 and made those obsolete. (Technically CSS 1 obsoleted them, but CSS 2 came at a time when browser support was getting decent).

Apply the text-align property to the option elements.

```
option { 
    text-align: center;
}
```

Note that due to the way different browsers have implemented the rendering of select elements, this does not enjoy universal support amount commonly used browsers.

The W3C host [a CSS tutorial](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Web_Standards_Curriculum#CSS) if you need it.

Comment: i see your logic, i tried this and implemented it successfully for a text field yet it doesn't work with a dropdown list

Comment: As I said "Note that due to the way different browsers have implemented the rendering of select elements, this does not enjoy universal support amoung commonly used browsers."

Comment: does Chrome support this? what browser is your recommendation?

Comment: It doesn't on the platform I use. I would recommend Chrome.

Comment: I just said it didn't. I'd still recommend it as a browser.